# UIScrollView + UITableView + Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have read that is not very recommended to have the UIScrollView with a UITableView inside, however i would like to test it and switch back to the idea of a UITableView without the scrollview as the last option.

What i tried is:

```
UIView => MAIN VIEW of the UIViewController
 - UIView => FOR a fixed header in the view
 -- UIButton on the right of this view
 - UIScrollView => For the rest of the view
 -- UIView => The container view of the UIScrollView
 --- UILabel => Top Label
 --- UITableView => The table
 --- UILabel => Bottom Label
```

I set disabled the scroll in the UITableView as i have the scroll in the ScrollView. I think i set all the constraints but still Xcode complains about:
ScrollView Need constraints for scrollable  content width
ScrollView Need constraints for scrollable  content heigh

If i don't fix this problem i dont see any row in the table view:
[image]

If i let Xcode solve the problems of the constraints:
[image]

However you can't scroll the UIScrollview also the design is not what i wanted as i would like to see all the 40 rows and later the bottom label, i don't want a scroll of the table view as i want the scrollview to do scroll of the top label, all the rows and the bottom label (the idea is that i would like to add more things there).

These are the constraints:
[image]

For simplicity the cell is a basic cell at this moment, i know later i will have to do extra things for Autolayout to work with dynamic cells.

Can you please let me know what can be happening

Comment: `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so seems you're trying to embed a scroll view into another scroll view?

Comment: @Cristik i know that, but i have disabled scroll view in UITableView.

Comment: Still, you're trying to embed a scroll view into a scroll view, regardless the settings you try to make on the embedded one. Don't be surprised if unexpected behaviour occurs :)

Comment: There's not anything wrong with having nested Scroll Views per-se.  There was a really neat video at WWDC a few years ago where they repeatedly demonstrated using nested Scroll Views to accomplish complex effects.

Comment: BTW, won't a table/section header and footer help you there, to avoid the need of embedded scroll views?

Comment: @Miguel - this can be done fairly easily by subclassing `UITableView` and having it auto-size its height, but... is there a reason you don't want to use table Header and Footer views?

Comment: @DonMag my idea was to add some icons in the future on the left that would be out of the scroll. Do you have any link where i would explain the option of subclassing UITableView approach. I'm thinking in the idea of table Header and Footer views if i don't find a better working solution.

Comment: @Miguel what do you assume other possible solutions are better than table header/footer? Why do you want to avoid them?

Answer (score 0):

Your comment *"my idea was to add some icons in the future on the left that would be out of the scroll"* doesn't really make any sense. If you want non-scrolling icons, just place them outside of the table view.

Putting a table view in a scroll view is not impossible... however, you lose the efficiency of reusable cells.

If you have 40 relatively "light weight" cells, probably not a big deal.

But suppose your cells are "heavy"? As in, several images, controls, labels, etc? And, suppose you have 100+ cells? Then you're unnecessarily overloading memory usage.

However, if you really want to try your approach, you can subclass `UITableView` like this:

```
// non-scrolling table view that automatically sets its
//  intrinsicContentSize based on its cells
final class AutoHeightTableView: UITableView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        isScrollEnabled = false
        setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    }
    
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    
    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return contentSize
    }
    
}
```

Now, your table view will act much like a multi-line label, setting its height based on its content.

Here's a complete example:

```
class DashBoardViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var autoHeightTableView: AutoHeightTableView!
    
    let sampleStrings: [String] = [
        "A sample string.",
        "Sample string with\ntwo rows.",
        "Sample string with enough text to cause word-wrapping.",
        "Sample string with enough text to cause word-wrapping, even if we have a very wide table (such as an iPhone in Landscape Orientation)."
    ]
    
    var numRows: Int = 1
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        autoHeightTableView.dataSource = self
        autoHeightTableView.delegate = self
        
        autoHeightTableView.register(SimpleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    @IBAction func addRowTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        // add a row
        numRows += 1
        autoHeightTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func removeRowTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        // remove a row, but keep at least 1
        numRows -= 1
        numRows = max(1, numRows)
        autoHeightTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension DashBoardViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numRows
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell
        let s = sampleStrings[indexPath.row % sampleStrings.count]
        c.theLabel.text = "Row \(indexPath.row) - \(s)"
        return c
    }
}

class SimpleCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        theLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
    
}
```

and a Storyboard to use with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="2DO-DK-DvL">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17703"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Dash Board View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="g75-XE-t5u">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="2DO-DK-DvL" customClass="DashBoardViewController" customModule="VeryTemp" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="O6N-jW-fEC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="SJM-7N-dTP" userLabel="ButtonView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="60"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aEu-IP-rXM">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="101" y="10" width="85" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.49327188729999999" blue="0.47399842739999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
                                        <inset key="contentEdgeInsets" minX="10" minY="0.0" maxX="10" maxY="0.0"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="Add Row"/>
                                        <state key="highlighted">
                                            <color key="titleColor" red="0.83741801979999997" green="0.83743780850000005" blue="0.83742713930000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        </state>
                                        <connections>
                                            <action selector="addRowTapped:" destination="2DO-DK-DvL" eventType="touchUpInside" id="QCw-Z5-VC0"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xrr-ve-UDf">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="196" y="10" width="114" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.49327188729999999" blue="0.47399842739999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
                                        <inset key="contentEdgeInsets" minX="10" minY="0.0" maxX="10" maxY="0.0"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="Remove Row"/>
                                        <state key="highlighted">
                                            <color key="titleColor" red="0.83741801979999997" green="0.83743780850000005" blue="0.83742713930000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        </state>
                                        <connections>
                                            <action selector="removeRowTapped:" destination="2DO-DK-DvL" eventType="touchUpInside" id="cZu-vf-pDE"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </button>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.83741801979999997" green="0.83743780850000005" blue="0.83742713930000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="60" id="09y-jl-yti"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="xrr-ve-UDf" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="0Se-yT-hhY"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="xrr-ve-UDf" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="aEu-IP-rXM" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="Bf2-5m-rCJ"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="aEu-IP-rXM" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="SJM-7N-dTP" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="YoS-xx-NXR"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="xrr-ve-UDf" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="10" id="ZN7-IA-HyF"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="xrr-ve-UDf" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="SJM-7N-dTP" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="fOU-kX-dYl"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="aEu-IP-rXM" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="vKl-iB-du9"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="5tP-7Y-LPu">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="60" width="320" height="420"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" placeholderIntrinsicWidth="infinite" placeholderIntrinsicHeight="320" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="rE3-Cv-Een" userLabel="ScrollContentView">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="320"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Active" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WZM-qS-dOD">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="304" height="30"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="IMg-Wn-BgL"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="f4v-Zc-2KD" customClass="AutoHeightTableView" customModule="VeryTemp" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="46" width="304" height="228"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                                            </tableView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Assigned" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="HPf-Zx-zNZ">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="282" width="304" height="30"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.97680455450000003" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="yqD-Mj-ksF"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemOrangeColor"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="HPf-Zx-zNZ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="140-cK-vKT"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="HPf-Zx-zNZ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="f4v-Zc-2KD" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="3yP-CX-WkR"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="HPf-Zx-zNZ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="BoD-9D-w0x"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="WZM-qS-dOD" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="Gg5-xY-Cwl"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="f4v-Zc-2KD" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="WZM-qS-dOD" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="KtX-GG-0hK"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="f4v-Zc-2KD" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="ZYI-Be-xwl"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="WZM-qS-dOD" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="rE3-Cv-Een" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="gd8-b8-jns"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="f4v-Zc-2KD" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="rE3-Cv-Een" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="jxB-sB-07D"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="HPf-Zx-zNZ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="rE3-Cv-Een" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="oIJ-Ck-Fn1"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="WZM-qS-dOD" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="rE3-Cv-Een" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="sSz-2Y-Yg8"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBlueColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="rE3-Cv-Een" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="fnD-Eq-tO0" secondAttribute="leading" id="Qfc-ph-JoH"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="rE3-Cv-Een" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="fnD-Eq-tO0" secondAttribute="trailing" id="XN9-8n-zw2"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="rE3-Cv-Een" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="fnD-Eq-tO0" secondAttribute="top" id="ehk-so-dph"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="rE3-Cv-Een" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="AzI-2g-Rnq" secondAttribute="width" id="jDq-Zz-Sxk"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="rE3-Cv-Een" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="fnD-Eq-tO0" secondAttribute="bottom" id="sZW-ak-PM4"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="fnD-Eq-tO0"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="AzI-2g-Rnq"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="od6-UL-Lpv"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="od6-UL-Lpv" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="5tP-7Y-LPu" secondAttribute="bottom" id="2dd-pa-B3b"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="SJM-7N-dTP" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="od6-UL-Lpv" secondAttribute="top" id="BrD-hB-LgN"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="od6-UL-Lpv" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="5tP-7Y-LPu" secondAttribute="trailing" id="LGO-eJ-Odx"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="5tP-7Y-LPu" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="SJM-7N-dTP" secondAttribute="bottom" id="ShA-aH-tNi"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="5tP-7Y-LPu" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="od6-UL-Lpv" secondAttribute="leading" id="Y3a-Ku-y5C"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="SJM-7N-dTP" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="od6-UL-Lpv" secondAttribute="leading" id="iPv-pY-elL"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="od6-UL-Lpv" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="SJM-7N-dTP" secondAttribute="trailing" id="owk-qt-e66"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="autoHeightTableView" destination="f4v-Zc-2KD" id="dUe-Q7-MBs"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iKW-xF-1vd" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="341.25" y="100"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBlueColor">
            <color red="0.0" green="0.47843137254901963" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemOrangeColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.58431372549019611" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemYellowColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```